# How to get correct global variable with jupyter's timeit?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, numba

One first cell I have this:

```
from numba import cuda
@cuda.jit
def thread_counter_safe(global_counter):
    cuda.atomic.add(global_counter, 0, 1)  # Safely add 1 to offset 0 in global_counter array
```

On the next cell I have this:

```
global_counter = cuda.to_device(np.array([0], dtype=np.int32))
thread_counter_safe[64, 64](global_counter)
print('Should be %d:' % (64*64), global_counter.copy_to_host())

global_counter = cuda.to_device(np.array([0], dtype=np.int32))
%timeit thread_counter_safe[64, 64](global_counter)
print('Should be %d:' % (64*64), global_counter.copy_to_host())
```

Output of this second cell is something like this:

```
Should be 4096: [4096]
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop
Should be 4096: [168390656]
```

Jupyter Notebook's timeit carries the `global_counter` accross its iteration test. How do it get it to give back `global_counter` correctly?

Comment: you would need to reset the `global_counter` to zero as part of the function that you are running `timeit`on. You can't safely/easily do that from the `thread_counter_safe` cuda kernel, but you could `def` a new function that resets the `global_counter` to zero and then calls `thread_counter_safe`, and run `timeit` on that.

Comment: Got it. A wrapper function would do, but still prefer some flag or parameter when calling timeit.